# plotar gráfico série temporal onde no eixo x mostre todos os anos

Tags: r, séries-temporais

Quando ploto a série temporal normal plot(serie), alguns anos ficam subentendidos que existem, mas não aparecem. Teria uma forma de mostrar todos os anos da serie temporal horizontalmente no eixo x ?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Faz parte da ferramenta ocultar sozinho não?

Answer (score 4):

Para fazer o que pede, tem de começar por não incluir os eixos com o argumento `axes = "n"`. Depois usa-se a função `axis` para por a anotação dos eixos onde e como se quiser.

Primeiro vou criar uma série temporal, uma vez que não temos dados na pergunta.

```
set.seed(4745)    # torna os resultados reprodutíveis

x <- ts(rnorm(14), start = 2005, end = 2018)
```

Agora, o gráfico. Note que mesmo assim os anos podem não caber no gráfico. Então rodei 90 graus para ficarem perpendiculares ao eixo dos `x`. Isso é feito com `las = 2`.

```
plot(x, xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = 2005:2018, labels = 2005:2018, las = 2)
```

Gráfico:

[image: Série temporal com eixo dos x modificado]

Comment: Muito obrigado, exatamente o que eu queria !!